# Display formatted JSON in SSRS report

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008

I have a table where one field is JSON string.

"CX.UW.001": "03/08/2017", "CX.UW.001.AUDIT": "admin",

I want to produce an SSRS report where it appears in readable format like:

```
CX.UW.001: 03/08/2017
CX.UW.001.AUDIT: admin
```

Is it possible?

Comment: How is ```CX.UW.001: 03/08/2017 CX.UW.001.AUDIT: admin``` more readable than ```"CX.UW.001": "03/08/2017", "CX.UW.001.AUDIT": "admin",```?

Comment: Instead of single string, I want it to parse it into multiple lines. The length of the string is variable for each record/row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for multiple records, just about any parse/split function will do, or you can use a simple CROSS APPLY in concert with a little XML

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, JSON varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'"CX.UW.001": "03/08/2017", "CX.UW.001.AUDIT": "admin"')

Select A.ID
      ,DisplayAs = replace(B.RetVal,'"','')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.JSON,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as X
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  DisplayAs
1   CX.UW.001: 03/08/2017
1   CX.UW.001.AUDIT: admin
```

**Or If you want the string to wrap**

```
Select A.ID
      ,DisplayAs = replace(replace(JSON,',',char(13)),'"','')
 From  @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
1   CX.UW.001: 03/08/2017
    CX.UW.001.AUDIT: admin
```

Comment: @user7776056 Happy it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Right click that field, choose `expression`, locate `Text` from `Common Functions` category, use `Replace` function, should be the syntax like :

```
Replace (Fields!Yours.Value.Value,"""","")
```

Or in TSQL:

```
Select Replace(JSON_COLUMN,'"','')
From table
```